# Calculating Number of Unique Strings and Number of Occurrences Over Multiple Excel Columns

Tags: excel

Hello I have an excel dataset that contains 9000 rows and text strings in 18 separate columns. I would like to get the following information:

- a list of all the unique strings included within the 18 columns
- counts of number of occurrences of the text strings within the 18 columns

There is no difference if a value is in column #1 or column #18; I just need to be able to count the occurrences of each. I feel like this should be easy, but I can't find an easy way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: You could use any language that supports Hash lists, then just iterate over all the text and put it in the Hash list... easy

Comment: Use dictionary of key - your text, and value - your count. When I item not exist add (cell text, 1). When item does exist replace 1 with 1+1 =2

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA, you could rearrange your list into a single column, then use a Pivot Table.  It will give you your list and your counts.

Comment: My [Duplicate Master Addin](http://sdrv.ms/18pQI6C) will do this as well, plus given functionality to handle white space, case sensitivity etc

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you already got some reasonable answers in the comments but another solution is to use vlookup to see if answers are already present.  Assuming you have strings in column A-R, then in column S use

`s1 =1`

`s2 =if(iserror(vlookup(A2,A$2:A2,1,0),1,0)`

Drag s1 and s2 over 18 columns.  Then drag S2-AJ2 down 9000 rows.  Use a sum at the bottom of each column.  Basically it searches everything higher in the column, if `vlookup` finds a match, it won't error so `iserror` will be false, and the `if` will return a 0.  If `vlookup` can't find a match, it returns #N/A so `iserror` will be true and the `if` will return a 1.